# web service date pull method

Tags: php, html, soap

Ok..I'm not really good at explaining my question properly, but give it a try.  I now have a $get on html page, calling a php file to read the data from my c++ program through SOAP web service. eg

html

```
 $.get("server/testc.php?tablename="+tnamef, function(xmldata)
```

php

```
 $result=%client->getValue('tablename'=>'value')
```

c++

```
int test__getMobile(struct soap * soap, char * tablename, int * value)
```

I'm trying to make it when ever i change a value from my table, new value will immediately display on the html page. at the moment it is using ----setInterval---- to call this $get function every second, it works but it takes too much traffic, especially when I have 30 of those call $get on my page.

On such situation, is there anyway to achieve that value on html will only change when I update my value from tablename? please point out if you not clear about my problem, thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to push data to the page... General Umbrella term for this is Comet so youll want to start with that term and then find a method or application that fits your needs.